# Eyeshot disables touch events in the whole of application

Tags: wpf, touch-event, eyeshot

I have a WPF application that uses touch events (TouchDown, TouchMove, TouchUp). Everything works fine. But if I give the ViewportLayout (Eyeshot 11) component somewhere to the application, the touch events will stop working in the whole of application. Does anyone know why? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You seem to have a focus issue. use a connected mouse to click something else and then try the touch again does it work ?

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. If I put a touch event to the window of sample example (for example 'Arrows'), the application behaves the same way. The touch event is not triggered. I have to remove the viewportlayout component to trigger the touch events.

Comment: Window in the example 'Arrows' has FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=viewportLayout1}". If I delete this property, touch event still doesn't work. 
I do not set this property anywhere in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/217843288-Enable-multitouch-on-WPF-controls) and [here](https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001187713-Enable-multitouch-on-Eyeshot-WPF-control-when-added-programmatically) to see if helps